# Import.io (web-crawler) keeps querying without output

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, import.io

The example script by Import.io won't display any results after giving a query using a form. Everything is displayed on http://loop.netai.net/. 
The user is supposed to be able to give an input, for example intel i7, and then the script should query and display the results in a table. But, I don't even know if it is connecting to the data table on Import.io. (Press CTRL + U to display the scripts on the website).

Does anyone know what is causing it to be unable to display the results?

Comment: @atmd Well since it's not displaying any results from the data tables, what is the problem causing it? (This is also a import.io related question, but the mods suggested me to move it to stackoverflow with tags).

Answer (score 1):

You need to explore it with dev. tools. (**F12** - Chrome and IE, **Ctrl+Shift+I** in FF).
As I've tested there is request to import.io, but it fails (status 400):
[image]

Where have you got these JS files from? importio.js ?